# Appending more data to a layout variable

Tags: variable, template-layouts

I'm using template layouts, and setting variables with the {layout:set} tag.
Is there a way to append data to an already set variable?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for now, version 2.9, there isn't.

But I suggest you to ask EllisLab for it. I *guess* isn't that hard to implement, but they are possibly busy because of the [EECI Conf](http://www.expressionengineconference.com/).

This and an `output` parameter can be really useful.

Comment: I've used stash to fix the issue. It works fine. But it would be nice if it was made possible using layout variables.

Comment: Indeed, @Diederik. Indeed!